# Create a unique username based on first letter of first name and entire last name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with users. One column for the first name, one for the last name. I need to generate the usernames based on the first name and the last name and need to follow this pattern:

1. first letter of first name only
2. entire last name

if the combination is not unique, then add a number at the end of the last name, increment on each new identical occurence.

How can I achieve this with eloquent and Laravel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
$user_name = $first_name[0].'_'.$last_name;

$user_count = User::where('first_name', '=', $first_name)
        ->where('last_name', '=', $last_name)->count();
//your unique user_name
$user_name = $user_name.'_'.$user_count+1;
```

This is just an approach. You can do it by any other way too.

Answer (score 2):

```
// original username
$user_name = "{$first_name[0]}_{$last_name}";


// if you have  a username column
$user_count = User::where('username', $user_name)->count();

// or 

// using first name and last name
$user_count = User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', $first_name[0])
        ->where('last_name', '=', $last_name)
        ->count();

// append digit if exists
if ($user_count > 0) {
  $user_name .= "_$user_count";
}
```